# How to remove an appended content in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently designing a web page using javascript, html and css. The page is a seat booking seat which allows the user to select and unselect seats. I have managed to get the page to display id of the seat when the user have selected a seat, but I am having problems trying to remove id from the display if user unselects the seat.

Below is the javascript code

```
$('.available, .unavailable, .selected').click(function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('class');
    if (ID == 'n unavailable' || ID == 'p unavailable') {
        alert ('Seat is already booked. Please select another seat.');
    }
    else if (ID == 'n selected' || ID == 'p selected') {
        alert ('You have now unselected this seat.');
        $(this).html('<img src = "free.gif"/>');
        $(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('available');
        y--;
        $("#seats").html("Number of seats selected: " + y);
        $("#list").remove($(this).attr('id'));
    }
    else {
        alert ('You have now reserved this seat. You can unselect it by clicking the seat again.');
        $(this).html('<img src = "selected.gif"/>');
        $(this).removeClass('available').addClass('selected');
        y++;
        $("#seats").html("Number of seats selected: " + y);
        $("#list").append($(this).attr('id') + "</br>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Add uncheck listener and remove it , you made a great progress till now

Comment: Can you post your example on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider appending to the list an actual element that you can later find and remove, instead of plain text

Appending:

```
var appendId = $(this).attr('id') 
$("#list").append("<div id='seat_"+appendId +"'>" + appendId + "</div>");
```

Removing:

```
$("#seat_"+$(this).attr('id')).remove();
```

Comment: it's suppose to remove the selected id from the list that is displayed

Comment: Yes, but the way you are appending it to the list element is as text separated by line breaks. There is no efficient way of finding and removing parts of text from inside an element, that is why i suggested wrapping that text in an element that you can easily select later, like a <div> (results in a line break as default), a <span> or even a <li> (probably the semantically correct element for this situation). Just give it an id you can recalculate later (like in the suggested code)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that you are using `alert()`, this is very bad practice to post messages to users. consider a different approach (if you want I can hint to the right direction.

The second thing to note is that `remove()` works on an element in jQuery. It removes either the current selected result set or a new result set based on the current result set `$('#seats').remove('.reserved')`, would remove elements with a class `reserved` found in the first result set (the element with the id `seats`).

The third thing, to note is that jQuery has a rather useful method called [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), use it!

Fourth and last, here's a revamped version of your code that should work:

```
$('.available, .unavailable, .selected').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('unavailable')) {
        alert ('Seat is already booked. Please select another seat.');
        return;
    }

    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        alert ('You have now unselected this seat.');
        $this
            .html('<img src = "free.gif"/>')
            .removeClass('selected')
            .addClass('available')
        ;
        y--;
        $("#seats").html("Number of seats selected: " + y);
        $('#reserved-'+$this.attr('id')).remove();
        return;
    }

    alert ('You have now reserved this seat. You can unselect it by clicking the seat again.');
    $this
        .html('<img src = "selected.gif"/>')
        .removeClass('available')
        .addClass('selected')
    ;
    y++;
    $("#seats").html("Number of seats selected: " + y);
    $("#list").append(
        $('<p/>')
            .attr('id','reserved-'+$this.attr('id'))
            .html($this.attr('id'))
    );
});
```

Also I'd consider removing `unavailable` and `available`. An element without those two classes and without `selected`, would be in a "default" state that in your application has no meaning. Consider revamping to `selected` and `reserved`. Reserved would be already taken seats, selected would be currently selected seats by the end user and those elements without either class, would be in a default state: free for anyone to take.